# Reverse proxy a site with SNI support using kubernetes nginx-ingress

Tags: ssl, nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I am setting a reverse proxy using kubernetes nginx-ingress, but I don't know how to add nginx parameters to the configuration, specifically: [proxy_ssl_server_name](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_server_name). How do I set ingress parameters in yaml configurations?

I already tried using the [server-snippet](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-snippet) annotation, but it seems like  it's not adding the parameter to the nginx.conf file in the cluster pods.

Here is the current code for the reverse proxy:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: formstack
  namespace: serves
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: fluidsignal.formstack.com
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: formstack
  namespace: serves
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost: "fluidsignal.formstack.com"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - fluidattacks.com
    secretName: fluidattacks-cert
  rules:
  - host: fluidattacks.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: formstack
          servicePort: 443
        path: /forms(.*)
```

After setting up the proxy, I get a `502 Bad Gateway` error from Nginx. After looking at the pods logs, I see I'm getting the following openssl error: `SSL: error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:SSL alert number 40`, which is why I want to add the parameter I mentioned before.

Answer (score 11):

I just figured out that I was indeed using the right annotation: `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet`,

But I needed to add an extra parameter: `proxy_ssl_name`

Adding the following code fixed the problem:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
  proxy_ssl_name fluidsignal.formstack.com;
  proxy_ssl_server_name on;
```

Everything seems to be working fine now :D

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution

Comment: Even though these directives appear to be supported by annotations (https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#backend-certificate-authentication), the snippet is required to use them in this situation. https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/6728 should fix the annotations.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is almost right but instead of `server-snippet` the `configuration-snippet` should be used.

The first one (`server-snippet`) will add configuration on the entire server level (the whole ingress server) and the last one (`configuration-snippet`) will be applied inside the nginx `location` that current ingress object is related to

```yaml
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
  proxy_ssl_name fluidsignal.formstack.com;
  proxy_ssl_server_name on;
```